# How can I create a link in the logo of the SLDSGlobalHeader component?

Tags: reactjs, salesforce-lightning

I'm using the `react salesforce lightning design system`'s  [Global Header component](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-headers/). I would like to add a link to the logo, but I don't know how to do it. There's a prop for the src of the logo, but no subcomponent for customizing the logo or a prop to make it linkable.

It looks easy to do in rendered html:

```
<header class="slds-global-header_container">
  <div class="slds-global-header slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
    <div class="slds-global-header__item">
      <div class="slds-global-header__logo" style="background-image:url(mylogo.svg)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

But I don't know how to access it from code, since my source looks like this:

```
<SLDSGlobalHeader logoSrc="mylogo.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a different website you can just wrap it under a anchor tag

```
<a href="">LOGO HERE</a>
```

Or, if you want to redirect somewhere in your app, you need react-router-dom and you either wrap it under a Link tag

```
<Link to="/">LOGO HERE</Link>
```

or create an onClick action that will push the history to the page you want

```
const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/')
}
```

[Check this, react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Hi @darksz, thanks! But I'm using this component, the Global Header from `lightning` library. I would like to be able to wrap my logo in a link, like you described, but without having to rewrite my entire header